# Excel Match() returns a value, although the lookup value is not in the array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

As you can see in the screenshot, MATCH() returns a value where it shouldn't.

✅ The lookup value is referenced to an array (in this case: $AB$18:$AB$22 -> the red box in the screenshot)

✅For some values, MATCH() returns, #N/A, which is perfectly fine, as the lookup value is not in the array

✅ For others, it returns the correct positional value (e.g. for 1604, it returns 4, which is the correct position)

❌ Problem: Sometimes, Match returns a Value, where there should be #N/A instead

❌ For example: See the line, where it says "1705", it returns "5", which is not true.

What can I do, to make this right?

Additinal Info:

- For specific reasons, the numbers are stored as text, so I tried a workaround with the TEXT() function, which usually works fine.

[image: Screenshot: Match returns wrong value]

Comment: You didn't specify the *third* argument of `MATCH` as 0, which is an exact match.

Comment: Thank you! That is the soulution, @Rory